# Using del in gulp.series()

Tags: javascript, gulp

I try to clean folder before start tasks in gulp 4

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    del.sync('folder/*');
});

gulp.task('foo', gulp.series('clean', 'something'));
```

It doesn't work, because `'clean'` task must return some stream. I've found workaround:

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    del.sync('folder/*');
    var emptyStream = gulp.src([]).pipe(gulp.dest('/'));
    return emptyStream;
});
```

, but still hope to find a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gulp allows three options for managing asynchronicity. First, if a function completes (returns nothing/undefined, or a simple value) gulp considers the task done and moves on. However, if your task is an asynchronous task (as much is in node) then you...

1. Return a stream. `return gulp.src(...).pipe(gulp.dest(...));` note the return value is a stream because gulp.src and .pipe return streams.
2. Return a [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/).
3. Use a callback. if you place a variable in the function's argument then gulp will expect the callback to be called and wait for that to happen. Giving the callback a value as an argument is considered a failure and calling it without a value is considered a success.

In the case of del, it doesn't do the first two but takes a callback which it handles the same as in scenario 3 above.

```
gulp.task('clean', function(done) {
  del(['output'], done);
});
```

#### Examples

Here is an example of using a callback manually called with a stream:

```
gulp.task('foo', function(done) {
  gulp.src('input')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output'))
    .on('end', function() {
      done();
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      done(err);
    });
});
```

Since streams are so common returning one will do the above for you. (Note the `done` was removed so gulp won't expect it to be called).

```
gulp.task('foo', function() {
  return gulp.src('input')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
});
```

Not everything can be a stream and call backs can be daunting to manage so you can instead return a promise:

```
gulp.task('foo', function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that with del() v2.x+ the callback argument no longer exists. Instead, del() returns a Promise, so you achieve the same result via something like `del(...).then(function(){...})`

Answer (score 5):

you can also pass the callback to clean task to get the stream returned

```
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['output'], cb);
});
```

have a look [here](https://coderwall.com/p/-ii7jw/running-gulp-tasks-in-series)

Comment: doesn't work by me, it starts the clean task and after that the process suddenly ends.

Comment: `return del(["output"]);` what works with the current version

Answer (score 4):

Directly from [gulp 4.0 samples](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0#sample-gulpfilejs), simply return the del promise:

```
function clean() {
  // You can use multiple globbing patterns as you would with `gulp.src`,
  // for example if you are using del 2.0 or above, return its promise
  return del([ 'assets' ]);
}
```